# How to access an XML element in a single go?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML string like below:

```
<root>
    <Test1>
        <Result time="2">ProperEnding</Result>
    </Test1>
    <Test2></Test2>
```

I have to operate on these elements. Most of the time the elements are unique within their parent element. I am using XDocument. I can remember that there is a way to access an element like this.

```
XNode resultTest1 = GetNodes("/root//Test1//result")
```

But I forgot it.  It is possible to access the same using linq:

```
doc.root.Elements.etc.etc.
```

But I want it using a single string as shown above. Can anybody say how to make it?

Comment: I am waiting to get the point.

Comment: People think that they are too smart and problems like these are too boring for them, lol. What do you want to do with data from this xml?

Comment: I never heard that making bore is a crime to get the downvote. One thing I am sure they are good in only one language. I am trying to modify the contents of the xml. I am able to do that using some other ways. But this will come handy.

Comment: The problem on stackoverflow is when people see a trivial problem for them or repetitive they tend to downvote as far as I see...

Answer (score 1):

[Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will skip any number level of intermediate nodes, e.g. this will skip over `root` and `Test1`:

```
doc.Decendants("Result")
```

Also note that you can use XPath with Linq2Xml as well, e.g. [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
doc.XPathSelectElements("/root/Test1/Result");
```

You can skip intermediate levels of the hierarchy with `//` (or use `//` at the start of the xpath string to skip the root)

```
"/root//Result"
```

One caveat - Xml is case sensitive , so `Result` and `result` are not the same element.

Comment: Thanks for Short and very useful explanation

Answer (score 1):

The string you're referring to (`"/root//Test1//result"`) is an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression.

You can use it with LINQ to XML classes (like `XDocument`) using `XPathEvaluate`, `XPathSelectElement`, and `XPathSelectElements` extension methods.

You can find more info about these methods on MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xpath.extensions_methods(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xpath.extensions_methods%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

To make them work, you need `using System.Xml.XPath` at the top of your file and `System.Xml.Linq.dll` assembly referenced (which is probably already there).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load your xml using `XDocument`:

```
// loads xml file with root element
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");
```

Now you can append LINQ statements to your `xml` variable like this:

```
var retrieveSomeSpecificDataLikeListOfElementsAsAnonymousObjects = xml.Descendants("parentNodeName").Select(node => new { SomeSpecialValueYouWant = node.Element("elementNameUnderParentNode").Value }).ToList();
```

You can mix and do whatever you want - above is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking?

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("YourXML");
XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/root/Test1/result");
```